# How to choose the rows where ColumnX=1 but ≠2?

Tags: mysql

The task I have to complete is：choose the `Titre` which for which `NumCritere` equals 1 but does not equal to 2.

There two tables: `Biens [ RefBien, Titre ]`, e.g.:

```
RefBien 1       Titre 1 ,                       
RefBien 2       Titre 2 ,                        
RefBien 3       Titre 3 ,
```

And `EvaluationsBiens [ NumCritere#, RefBien# ]`, e.g.:

```
Num 1           Refbien 1,
Num 1           Refbien 2,
Num 1           Refbien 3,
Num 2           Refbien 1,
Num 2           Refbien 3,
NUM 3           Refbien 1,
```

I have tried：

```
SELECT NumCritere, Titre
FROM evaluationsbiens
JOIN biens ON evaluationsbiens.RefBien = biens.RefBien
where NumCritere ="1"
and NumCritere<>"2";
```

I get all the `titre` rows where `NumCritere=1` as result.

Can you tell me what's wrong with my code? Or do you have a diffierent way to do it?

Comment: You should format your question a bit better. Use the buttons on top of the editor, and look at the preview please. There is also help. About your question: if something is 1, it is useless to also say that it is not 2. Because things that are 1 are never 2 (as they are allready 1). I think you might be looking for something different, logic-wise. Even if you meant to get both things that are 1 together with things that are not 2 (=1 OR !=2), it's still quite useless for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you for remind me ,now is better?

Comment: Are those actual values? I.e. if you `SELECT DISTINCT NumCitere FROM evaluationsbiens`, "Num 1" is actually among the output?

Comment: What @Nanne is trying to say (i think) is that maybe your logic probably will be something like NumCritere ="1" and SomeOtherField <> "2". As he said there is no need to put in the same criteria the same field equals to one value and different to other value this is impossible to happen.

Comment: I understand what's wrong with my code now ,but still don't see the way to put it right

Comment: Look at the table evaluationsbiens , one refbien can have more then one numcritere .im looking for the title of  refbien which have numcritere 1 but didn't have numcritere 2

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to return the `Titre` which is associated with any record who's `NumCritere` is 1 but NOT if its also associated with a record who's `NumCritere` is 2.

In which case this should work:

```
SELECT Titre
FROM evaluationsbiens
JOIN biens ON evaluationsbiens.RefBien = biens.RefBien
WHERE NumCritere = 1
AND evaluationsbiens.RefBien NOT IN (SELECT RefBien FROM evaluationsbiens WHERE NumCritere = 2)
```

Example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c5f09/36/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can join on a table twice.  Join once on 1, then left join on 2 and restrict the results to non-matches for the left join.

```
SELECT *
FROM biens
JOIN evaluationsbiens as e1 ON biens.RefBien = e1.RefBien AND e1.numCritere = 1
LEFT JOIN evaluationsbiens as e2 ON biens.RefBien = e2.RefBien and e2.numCritere = 2
WHERE e2.RefBien is NULL;
```

Comment: Good solution. I don't think MYSQL has an `==` operator but it will work with just `=`